# Makefile - Only Makes One of Two Libs

Tags: c, makefile, lib

I am new to makefile and am trying to compile several files.

First is called s-chat and the others are RWT (reader-writer) and DP (dining philosopher). They both use my list library, but s-chat needs it to compile with the -m32 flags.

This is what I tried to do: I called one libMonitor.a using lib-adders.o, lib_movers.o, lib_removers.o. The other one is liblist_32 using lib_adders_32.o, lib_removers_32.o, lib_movers_32.o. For some reason, only the first of these two libraries is made, and the other says it cannot find its first dependency.

```
PTHREADS  = /student/cmpt332/pthreads
RTT  = /student/cmpt332/rtt

CC       = gcc
CFLAGS   = -g
CPPFLAGS = -std=c90 -Wall -pedantic

.PHONEY: all clean

ARCH = $(shell uname -sm | tr -d ' ')

ifeq ($(ARCH),SunOS)
ARCH = $(PLATFORM)

PROCESSOR = "$(shell uname -p)"
ifeq ($(PROCESSOR),i386)
ARCH = i86pc
endif

endif

all: s-chat reader-writer-test dining-philosophers-test 

RWT_OBJS = reader-writer_$(ARCH).o reader-writer-monitor_$(ARCH).o Monitor_$(ARCH).o libMonitor_$(ARCH).a

reader-writer-test: CPPFLAGS += -I$(PTHREADS)
reader-writer-test: LDFLAGS += -L$(PTHREADS)/lib/$(ARCH)
reader-writer-test: LDLIBS += -lpthreads
reader-writer-test: $(RWT_OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

reader-writer_$(ARCH).o: reader-writer.c reader_writer_monitor.h Monitor.h

reader-writer-monitor_$(ARCH).o: reader-writer-monitor.c reader_writer_monitor.h Monitor.h

DP_OBJS = dining-philosophers_$(ARCH).o dining-philosophers-monitor_$(ARCH).o Monitor_$(ARCH).o libMonitor_$(ARCH).a

dining-philosophers-test: CPPFLAGS += -I$(PTHREADS)
dining-philosophers-test: LDFLAGS += -L$(PTHREADS)/lib/$(ARCH)
dining-philosophers-test: LDLIBS += -lpthreads
dining-philosophers-test: $(DP_OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

dining-philosophers_$(ARCH).o: dining-philosophers.c dining_philosophers_monitor.h Monitor.h

dining-philosophers-monitor_$(ARCH).o: dining-philosophers-monitor.c dining_philosophers_monitor.h Monitor.h

Monitor_$(ARCH).o: Monitor.c Monitor.h

list_adders.o: list_adders.c list.h
list_movers.o: list_movers.c list.h
list_removers.o: list_removers.c list.h

libMonitor_$(ARCH).a: list_adders.o list_movers.o list_removers.o
    ar rcs $@ $^


list_adders_32.o: CFLAGS += -m32
list_adders_32.o: LDFLAGS += -m32
list_adders_32.o: list_adders.c list.h
list_movers_32.o: CFLAGS += -m32
list_movers_32.o: LDFLAGS += -m32
list_movers_32.o: list_movers.c list.h
list_removers_32.o: CFLAGS += -m32
list_removers_32.o: LDFLAGS += -m32
list_removers_32.o: list_removers.c list.h

liblist_32_$(ARCH).a: list_adders_32.o list_movers_32.o list_removers_32.o
    ar rcs $@ $^

s-chat: CPPFLAGS += -I$(RTT)/include
s-chat: CFLAGS += -m32
s-chat: LDFLAGS += -L$(RTT)/lib/$(ARCH) -m32
s-chat: LDLIBS += -lRtt -lRttUtils
s-chat: s-chat.o liblist_32_$(ARCH).a
s-chat.o: s-chat.c

%_$(ARCH).o %_32_$(ARCH).o %.o %_32.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

%: %.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) $^ -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.a reader-writer-test dining-philosophers-test s-chat
```

This is the error I get:

```
ar rcs libMonitor_Linuxx86_64.a list_adders.o list_movers.o list_removers.o
ar: list_adders.o: No such file or directory
Makefile:66: recipe for target 'libMonitor_Linuxx86_64.a' failed
make: *** [libMonitor_Linuxx86_64.a] Error 1
```

And if I make s-chat last, libMonitor is made, but I get the exact same error with liblist_32 and it says it can't find list_adders_32.o

Anyone know what's going on and how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: btw: `.PHONY`...

Comment: I am not sure, but try removing the `.c` files from the requisite lines here: `list_adders.o: list_adders.c list.h` => `list_adders.o: list.h`.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Intro

> If a pattern rule has multiple targets, make knows that the rule’s recipe is responsible for making all of the targets. The recipe is executed only once to make all the targets.

```
%_$(ARCH).o %_32_$(ARCH).o %.o %_32.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Should be something like

```
%_$(ARCH).o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

%_32_$(ARCH).o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

%_32.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

But since it seems like all of your sources are in the same directory anyway, you could just delete these rules completely because make already has a built-in rule for `%.o: %.c`.